# How do I GET a png image through nodejs express app making a call to an API

Tags: node.js, rest, express, request, mime-types

I need to be able to return a png image from and API endpoint through nodejs express app.

When trying to return an image/svg file, it returns and renders as expected. But when |I try with a png file, I get some poorly encoded text like so:

```
�PNG  IHDR\���IDATx�]�U��:Ӂ�.��*��������]�{�A�A�(�� �\���1���   �� A@6���$�(�CXX|d��IUu�dz�渤�g��u�����sO�1��g��W�����~fv��+�TL�z�qןc��e��;��{��狿
```

Here is the code I have now:

```
const express = require('express')
const request = require('request-promise')
const port = 3000
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars')
const app = express()

const options = {
  method: 'GET',
  uri: 'https://www.google.co.uk/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'image/png',
    'Content-Type': 'image/png'
  }
}



app.get('/', (request, response) => {
    test(response)
})

app.listen(port, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.log('something bad happened', err)
  }
  console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`)
})


function test(resp){
 return request(options).then((data)=>{
    resp.header('Content-Type', options.headers['Content-Type']).send(data);
  }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
      data.render('error')
})
}
```

Comment: `res.header('Content-Type', options.headers['Content-Type']).send(data);`

Comment: Browser is still loading the string as above with content-type set in the response.

Comment: Its odd, still looking into it, it works if you just pipe it `request("http://...").pipe(resp);`

Comment: sidenote `data.render('error')` is wrong as data wont be set

Comment: @LawrenceCherone thanks, I will pipe it :). I think the image was being corrupted by trying to read as a string with wrong encoding (maybe?). I downloaded the broken png file and compared to the original and the hex data was similar but with some extra values in places.

Comment: Cool, yeah not sure what is going on lol, it was intermittently working on codesandbox, thought Buffer.from was a fix but that stopped working too, I thought request-promise might be doing something, tried just normal request (callback), but not that, was not much else to try so gave up, sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

Solution to my problem here. Thanks to @LawrenceCherone

```
const express = require('express')
const request = require('request-promise')
const port = 3000
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars')
const app = express()

const options = {
  method: 'GET',
  uri: 'https://www.google.co.uk/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'image/png'
  }
}

app.get('/', (request, response) => {
    response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/png')
    makeRequest(response)
})

app.listen(port, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.log('something bad happened', err)
  }
  console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`)
})


function makeRequest(resp){
    request(options.uri, options).pipe(resp)
}
```